# Calls between Node-Red services end in: RequestError: socket hang up

Tags: node.js, sockets, kubernetes, connection, node-red

We have a connection error that we don't know how to solve.

First, we have 3 Node-Red services and a third party backend. They call each other and have a requestTimeUp configured like this: Node1 52s -> Node2 51s -> Node3 50s -> BE.

Each node processes different information and they work fine. However, when the third party BE does not respond within 50 seconds, something breaks in the connection between Node1 and Node2 and we receive a RequestError: socket hang up on Node1 while the response seems to be sent correctly from Node2.

**Full explanation:**

When the flow arrives at Node3 and 50 seconds have passed with no response from the BE an exception is thrown at this Node and controlled. Then that error is sent with the following response to Node2.

```
{
    "httpCode": 504,
    "httpMessage": "Internal Server Error",
    "moreInformation": "BackEnd Timeout: [XXXX]".
}
```

Node2 receives the response and processes it. As it is an error there is nothing to do with this response and this node will send the same response to Node1.
Node2 does its job well, and ends up with the desired response.

Here Node1 should receive the response and process the error, however the response we get is as follows.

```
{
    "payload": "RequestError: socket hang up : http://XXXX",
    "statusCode": "ECONNRESET"
}
```

With this stackTrace:

```
RequestError: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:956:111)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:482:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:43:20)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:499:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:628:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:499:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

**Notes:**

We have checked the headers sent on each jump and everything seems to be fine, nothing different between a good call and this error.

We have made all requests with the default HttpRequest node.

All calls that have a TimeOut on the BE end up with this error. All other calls work fine.
The only thing we noticed, is that in the Node2 logs, the msg.req.aborted field has a true value, as if Node1 was closing the connection....

Tested on: Node-Red v2.0.5 with Node.js v14.17.3 and Node-Red v1.0.6 with Node.js v10.20.1

**Update:**

I notice that the error only happend when the code was executed on the services deployed on kubernetes. When it was executed locally or even from a docker image it worked as expected so I started making more test and I think is something related with kubernetes. All of our Node-red services are deployed there.

I could reproduce the error with the following code:

```
[{"id":"95afc81362ae6686","type":"inject","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":150,"y":120,"wires":[["28d3eaa9148b57fe","abbefffc92211444"]]},{"id":"28d3eaa9148b57fe","type":"function","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"service","func":"msg.url = \"serviceName:1880/test\"\nmsg.method = \"post\"\nmsg.requestTimeout = 56000\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":310,"y":120,"wires":[["df85a6d0209f33e8"]]},{"id":"df85a6d0209f33e8","type":"http request","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","method":"use","ret":"txt","paytoqs":"ignore","url":"","tls":"","persist":false,"proxy":"","authType":"","x":470,"y":120,"wires":[["5ece76d3e4c1ca83"]]},{"id":"5ece76d3e4c1ca83","type":"debug","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"1","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":650,"y":120,"wires":[]},{"id":"9d41a245138cded7","type":"catch","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","scope":null,"uncaught":false,"x":200,"y":240,"wires":[["a7422a4751397e96"]]},{"id":"a7422a4751397e96","type":"debug","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"3","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":350,"y":240,"wires":[]},{"id":"c2f3b9a425926d6b","type":"function","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","func":"msg = {\n    \"payload\": {\n        \"httpCode\": 504,\n        \"httpMessage\": \"Internal Server Error\",\n        \"moreInformation\": \"One or more producers failed. See details for more information\",\n        \"details\": [\n            {\n                \"target\": \"[scde1s]\",\n                \"message\": \"Time out of BackEnd: [Models].\"\n            }\n        ]\n    },\n    \"statusCode\": 504,\n\n    req : msg.req,\n    res :msg.res\n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":420,"y":400,"wires":[["128e53e76776a9ea","705b44898bf20cca"]]},{"id":"14ccdfd1343311e9","type":"http in","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","url":"/test","method":"post","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":120,"y":400,"wires":[["f97cdbba98c5025f"]]},{"id":"128e53e76776a9ea","type":"http response","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":560,"y":400,"wires":[]},{"id":"705b44898bf20cca","type":"debug","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"4","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":530,"y":340,"wires":[]},{"id":"f97cdbba98c5025f","type":"delay","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","pauseType":"delay","timeout":"51","timeoutUnits":"seconds","rate":"1","nbRateUnits":"1","rateUnits":"second","randomFirst":"1","randomLast":"5","randomUnits":"seconds","drop":false,"allowrate":false,"x":280,"y":400,"wires":[["c2f3b9a425926d6b"]]},{"id":"abbefffc92211444","type":"function","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"ingress","func":"msg.url = \"http://ingressHost/test\"\nmsg.method = \"post\"\nmsg.requestTimeout = 56000\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":320,"y":180,"wires":[["5c97785c2bfc83d0"]]},{"id":"5c97785c2bfc83d0","type":"http request","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"","method":"use","ret":"txt","paytoqs":"ignore","url":"","tls":"","persist":false,"proxy":"","authType":"","x":480,"y":180,"wires":[["701bec8d3c6a1c4b"]]},{"id":"701bec8d3c6a1c4b","type":"debug","z":"cbe74e3e98cc6655","name":"2","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":650,"y":180,"wires":[]}]
```

[image]

I don't have a lot of experience with k8s but I notice that the request failed only when we used the ingress to connect.
In the code that I shared both requests that end in debugs 1 and 2 are calling [POST]/test but each one connects with a diferent endpoint.
The first one uses the service like `serviceName:port/test` and the second one uses the ingress like `http://ingressHost/test`.

As you can see, in the debug 1 I got the expecte result, but in the debug 2 the socket failed.
If you made the call with localhost it also worked, so I think there is something wrong with our ingresses.

Is there any k8s configuration that could cause this errors?

Comment: Can you provide an example flow? You should be able to do all the Node-RED in one flow just by injecting different timeout values into the multiple http-request nodes.

Comment: @hardillb I updated the quiestion with a test flow and an explanation. It seems to be failing because of the k8s network...

Comment: It looks like the ingress controller is closing the socket for some reason and Node-RED is responding as it should. As to why the Ingress controller is closing the connection I can not say.